# Flowing circuit animation

Tags: css

[image]

My website has a div with just margins, and when the page loads, I want an effect of circuit (I got battery overlapped on the div) so from the positive terminal, the color of the circuit changes to yellow and then the yellow keeps on going to the negative terminal. Is this possible with CSS I am not completely sure about the power of CSS.

Here is the code of my div tag.

```css
#circuit {
  width: 80%;
  border: 10px solid navy;
  margin: 25px;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="circuit"></div>
```

Comment: kinda the effect of current flowing from +ve to -ve ( i know electrons actually move from -ve to +ve but i dont care about that in this website)

Comment: there's only borders here ?

Comment: I removed the cell and resistors for simplicity

Comment: Positive terminal ? If you see the pic, there is a + made it so its easier for others to understand :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A series of keyframe animations does the job. You'll need to modify duration and cumulative delay to get the speed you want.

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hstqcrgk/)**

```css
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.circuit-outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    margin: 5% 10% 0;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.circuit-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.current {
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.current.bottom-left {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 3px;
    -webkit-animation-name: zap1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .2s;
    animation-name: zap1;
    animation-duration: .2s;
}
.current.left {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 3px;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-animation-name: zap2;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-name: zap2;
    animation-delay: .2s;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}
.current.top {
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    -webkit-animation-name: zap3;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .7s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: zap3;
    animation-delay: .7s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
.current.right {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 3px;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-animation-name: zap2;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.7s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-name: zap2;
    animation-delay: 1.7s;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}
.current.bottom-right {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    -webkit-animation-name: zap4;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.2s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-name: zap4;
    animation-delay: 2.2s;
    animation-duration: .8s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zap1 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 20%;
    }
}
@keyframes zap1 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 20%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes zap2 {
    0% {
        height: 0;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes zap2 {
    0% {
        height: 0;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes zap3 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes zap3 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes zap4 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
@keyframes zap4 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circuit-outer">
  <div class="current bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="current left"></div>
  <div class="current top"></div>
  <div class="current right"></div>
  <div class="current bottom-right"></div>
  <div class="circuit-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? It creates a background and animates the position on hover. You can easily apply a special class on page load.

```css
#circuit {
  width: 80%;
  border: 10px solid navy;
  margin: 25px;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position:right bottom;
  transition:all 2s ease;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#circuit:hover {
  background-position:left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="circuit"></div>
```

---

---

Comment: Something like that but i want that effect to happen on the MARGIN not inside the div block :/ sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you're looking for:

```css
#circuit {
  position:relative;
  width: 450px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  border:1px solid;
  
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position:right bottom;
  transition:all 2s ease;
 
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#circuit:hover {
  background-position:left bottom;
}
.inner{
background:white;
position:absolute;
top:15%;
left:5%;
bottom:15%;
right:5%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="circuit"><div class='inner'></div></div>
```

Comment: it is getting close to what I wanted I updated my post (main page) and I want the yellow to go from the +ve terminal and to the -ve terminal